# Angular 4 - How to get the index of $event.currTarget from the ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular

**What Am I trying to accomplish**:
When the user press `enter` inside a `<p>` element, a new `<p>` element is added right after it. **it is possible that the user press the ENTER key on the 5th out o 70 views...**

**How Am i trying to do it**: On the `<p>` element, there is a `keyPress` Listener. When the `enter` key is pressed, I am trying to get the index of the current element and add one right after as follows:

```
let dom_view = e.currentTarget
let index = this.richtextbox.indexOf(dom_view);

this.richtextbox.insert(this.p_dom.createEmbeddedView(null),index+1);
```

**The issue i am facing**: index is always -1 as e.currentTarget (same as e.target) is not identified by the container! What is the right way to get the index?

**My Component code is**:

```
import {
  AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']

})
export class EditorComponent  implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('richtextbox', {read: ViewContainerRef}) richtextbox: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('p_dom') p_dom;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // insert a p element
    let view1 = this.p_dom.createEmbeddedView(null)
    this.richtextbox.insert(view1);
  }
  editor_keypress(e) {
    let dom_view = e.currentTarget

    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      let index = this.richtextbox.indexOf(dom_view);
      // notice that index is the index of the view that the user pressed
      // the enter on. there can be 1000 views... and i want to add the new 
      // view right after the one that the user pressed the enter on
      console.log('index = ', index)

      this.richtextbox.insert(this.p_dom.createEmbeddedView(null),index+1);
    }
  }
}
```

The HTML context is:

```
<ng-container #richtextbox>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #p_dom>
  <p contenteditable="true" (keypress)="editor_keypress($event)">I am editable test message</p>
</ng-template>
```

### Update

I ended up using `Renderer2`in order to manipulate the doms. The problem with the ViewRef is that i wasn't able to create Listenner with closure to the view as Described by  Bougarfaoi's Answer. If you want to have a look at the code, here is a [link](https://github.com/exhesham/electron-markdown-editor/tree/master/src/app) to the github code.

Comment: The <p> element doesn't have any id in your html. It's not what you are trying to get ?

Comment: Hi Brice, I am trying to get the view index in the containter. it looks like i cannot get the relevant ViewRef from the $event

Comment: ViewContainer contains views not DOM node. You can simply skip index in insert method

Comment: currentTarget is a html element not angular view

Comment: what is the best way to get the angular view from $event?

Comment: Have you tried `You can simply skip index in insert method` ?

Comment: i know it is possible, but i need the new view to be added right after the one with the event

Comment: In this case even if you know index you have to move index of other views. You're inventing the same thing as ngFor directive does https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L159-L170

Answer (score 1):

the passed value in `this.richtextbox.indexOf` must be of type `ViewRef` and you're passing to it an HTMLElement so here is the solution :

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhjl1f)**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('richtextbox', {read: ViewContainerRef}) richtextbox: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('p_dom') p_dom;
   view1
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // insert a p element
    this.view1 = this.p_dom.createEmbeddedView(null)
    this.richtextbox.insert(this.view1);
  }
  editor_keypress(e) {
    let dom = e.currentTarget


    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      let index = this.richtextbox.indexOf(this.view1);
      console.log(this.richtextbox);
      console.log('dom = ', dom)
      console.log('index = ', index)

      this.richtextbox.insert(this.p_dom.createEmbeddedView(null),index+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, however, for what i am trying to accomplish, it doesn't help me, as the user may press the `enter` on a view that is not view1. storing the views in a datastructure, doesn't look efficient. can you help me resolving this? best regards

Comment: or maybe is it possible to add a listener with closure to view1?

Comment: what's the problem with  storing the views in a data structure , how can you keep track of all views (<p>)

Comment: There must be a more efficient way - if each view has a listener and this listener holds its viewRef, then it will be much easier to accomplish what i am trying to do

Comment: your answer is useful in case there is only several views. still interesting how the real problem still can be handled

Comment: is there any problem with Renderer2